# How do I create a scheduled user-defined action that trims rows in TimescaleDB?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, timescaledb, retention

I'm monitoring, collecting and storing event data for different organizations in my TimescaleDB.

I have a TimescaleDB with one database. Each organization has its own schema in that database. Each schema has two tables: A **device** table and an **event** table.

The device table stores information about the devices of the given organization, while the event table is a Time Series table that stores all the events collected from the different devices. The event table has a column (foreign key) that points to the device table.

This is how my database is structured

```
▼ Servers (1)
  ▼ TimescaleDB Cloud
    ▼  Databases (1)
      ▼  myTimescaleDB
        ▼ Schemas (12)
          ▼ organization_1 (12)
            ▼ Tables (2)
              ▼ device
                ▼ Columns (3)
                    device_id
                    device_name
                    device_type
              ▼ event
                ▼ Columns (5)
                    event_id
                    time
                    device_id (fk)
                    event_source
                    event_type
          ▼ organization_2 (12)
            ▼ Tables (2)
              ▼ device
                ▼ Columns (3)
                    device_id
                    device_name
                    device_type
              ▼ event
                ▼ Columns (5)
                    event_id
                    time
                    device_id (fk)
                    event_source
                    event_type
```

I want to create a scheduled user-defined action that basically makes sure that each device only has a maximum of 10.000 events. So every - let's say 5 minutes - the user-defined action should count the number of events of each device in each schema. Any device that has more than 10.000 events should be trimmed to only have 10.000. We always want to trim the old events though. How do I do this?

Comment: There are a few things to tackle here before giving an example, mostly based on how TimescaleDB is (typically) used most effectively. Can you help explain why the 10k row limit exists? Is it to save storage space or some other technical/application reason?

Comment: @Ryan The 10k limit exists to save space. I've experienced that sometimes if one of the devices have an error, it'll throw the same error event around 150 times per minute. That means I'll have millions of rows in my event table just for this one device, reporting the exact same error over and over again. The way I want to deal with it is simply put a 10.000 row limit on each device.

Comment: So @jontasdb headed right into retention policies which is why I was asking. You cannot guarantee the number of rows per chunk, however. Retention is based on time.

In your case, if the issue is duplicate data, there are probably other ways to solve this. With less duplication, you could retain based on time more easily, too.

Have you considered trying something like INSERT ON CONFLICT to reduce duplicate messages? It's a bit more challenging with timestamps, but sounds like it's worth investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your device sending the data every X seconds? Because you could also create a retention policy if you have such a case. Let's say you have it receiving a new event every 5 seconds for each device, so you have 12 per minute and (12 * 60 * 24) = 17280 per day. So, 10k of 17280 is around 58% of the day.

You can also do some math to get a number of hours and use a retention policy to remove the rest.

That would be the adoption of retention policies that in the end are background jobs doing exactly the removal. The only difference is that they're much more efficient because they drop the chunks completely. If that's not the case, you need to use a custom background job as you requested help here.

To build the proper scenario, you can try to build a query to validate what you want. Here is a snippet using a window function to get the proper record:

```sql
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT time,
           device,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device
                                 ORDER BY time DESC ) AS rank
      FROM conditions )
 SELECT *
   FROM summary
 WHERE rank = 10000;
```

It would return something like:

```sql
┌────────────────────────┬────────┬───────┐
│          time          │ device │ rank  │
├────────────────────────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 2000-01-07 21:17:05+00 │      0 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 10:56:19+00 │      1 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:37:45+00 │      2 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:53:32+00 │      3 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:42:57+00 │      4 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 10:13:28+00 │      5 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:30:52+00 │      6 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:38:55+00 │      7 │ 10000 │
│ 2000-01-04 11:46:30+00 │      8 │ 10000 │
```

Now it's just a matter to combine the query with the delete clause:

```sql
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT time,
           device,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device
                                 ORDER BY time DESC ) AS rank
      FROM conditions )
 DELETE FROM conditions USING summary
   WHERE summary.rank = 10000 and conditions.time < summary.time and summary.device = conditions.device;
```

Confirming it worked as you expected:

```sql
select device, count(1) from conditions group by 1;
┌────────┬───────┐
│ device │ count │
├────────┼───────┤
│      0 │ 10000 │
│      1 │ 10000 │
│      2 │ 10000 │
│      3 │ 10000 │
│      4 │ 10000 │
│      5 │ 10000 │
│      6 │ 10000 │
```

And you can wrap it into the background function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE limit_devices_data(job_id int, config jsonb) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'DELETING in the job % with config %', job_id, config;
   WITH summary AS (
    SELECT time,
           device,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY device
                                 ORDER BY time DESC ) AS rank
      FROM conditions )
 DELETE FROM conditions USING summary
   WHERE summary.rank = 10000 and conditions.time < summary.time and summary.device = conditions.device;
  COMMIT;
END
$$;
```

And add the job to run every 5 minutes or depending on your need:

```sql
SELECT add_job('limit_devices_data','5 minutes', initial_start => now() + INTERVAL '5 seconds');
```

If you have too much data, maybe you'll need to increase the max_runtime:

```sql
SELECT alter_job(job_id, max_runtime =>  INTERVAL '1 minute');
```

As you have several tables under different schemas, I'd recommend you take a look at [execute combined with format](https://newbedev.com/how-to-use-execute-format-using-in-postgres-function) to iterate over several tables. You can query the hypertable names using [timescaledb_information.hypertables](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/hypertables/) view.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. Just to answer the first part, each device sends data every 3 minutes (if it has picked up any events). However the amount it sends is not fixed. it entirely depends on how many events there was in those 3 minutes, so there is no way of calculating it. For me it would be much better to use a retention policy. If there was a way of doing this using a retention policy, I'd surely prefer that.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd also suggest you give try on compression and maybe continuous aggregates to see if you can reduce the disk usage but keep your data around. 
Not sure if you're familiar with the toolkit and the statistical functions we have to [downsample](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/downsample/) the data.

Here is a full [example](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/user-defined-actions/example-downsample-and-compress/).